# Получить имя созданного объекта?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

У меня все созданные объекты идут в список(ArrayList):

```
Класс.метод(arg0, arg1);
```

Метод:

```
public static void метод(String arg0, String arg0){
        список.add(new Класс(arg0, arg1));
    }
```

Как мне получить имя созданного объекта? Не тот который идёт в аргументах, а тот который должен быть при создании объекта:

```
Класс вот_это_имя = new Класс(arg0, arg1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этого имени не существует, но я догадался, что Вам нужно.

```
public static Класс метод(String arg0, String arg0) {
  Класс result = new Класс(arg0, arg1);
  список.add(result);
  return result;
}

Класс k = Класс.метод(arg0, arg1);
```